# How to populate a new column in a new database when transferring data from a old database

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a old database (using MariaDB) and I have to make a new one that's close to the same but has a few differences, and I have to insert all the data from the old one into the new one. I've populated the new one with all the equal data, but I'm stuck on getting the 'new' data into it.

The change is in the old database there was a column in multiple tables containing a country name, but in the new database Country has it's own table, so instead of a country name in a column, it is instead just the foreign key CountryID from the country table.

So the issue is I have to populate the new columns CountryID with whatever the Countries CountryID is. For example, if the country field in the customers table in the old database was USA, when I translate the data, instead of putting USA it has to go to the new Country table, find the CountryID that is equal to USA, and put that ID in the field instead. (Something like this)

```
Old Customers Table
--------------------
Country
USA
Canada



New Customers Table
-------------------
CountryID
3
7

CountryTable
----------
CountryID                    CountryName
3                            USA
7                            Canada
```

I know it's probably just a simple insert into with some condition but can't figure out the proper syntax for it.

I've tried different insert into statements similar to the following but keep getting errors:

```
insert into newDatabase.customers(CountryID)
     select oldDatabase.customers.Country
     from oldDatabase.customers
     where oldDatabase.customers.country = newDatabase.countryTable.CountryName;
```

```
insert into newDatabase.customers(CountryID)
     select oldDatabase.customers.Country
     from oldDatabase.customers
     inner join newDatabase.countryTable as c on c.countryName = oldDatabase.customers.Country
     where oldDatabase.customers.country = newDatabase.countryTable.countryName;
```

Comment: Can you share the error messages? They should provide enough information to help formulate a correct query

Comment: When running the first one the error I get is: "Unknown column 'newDatabase.countryTable.countryName' in 'where clause' "            

When running the second the error I get is: "Incorrect integer value: 'Germany' for column newDatabase.customers.CountryID at row 26"

Answer (score 0):

The end goal is you want to insert the id from `CountryTable` into your new customers table, which means you are going to need that table. You are inserting the data from the old customers table, so it'll look like this:

```
INSERT INTO newdb.customers(CountryID)
SELECT ct.CountryID
  FROM olddb.customers as oldc
       INNER JOIN newdb.country_table as ct
               ON ct.CountryName = oldc.Country;
```

You don't need a `WHERE` clause because you aren't trying to filter the rows from the old customers table. You just need the ID from the country table to be mapped with your old customers table. For that reason you are `JOIN`ing by the country's name to the country table to get that extra information.

Comment: What you say about the process makes sense but when I do this I get a error saying "duplicate entry ' ' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: What's the output of the query I gave you without the INSERT line? You can verify you're getting the data you want before doing the query itself. You should be getting a column of IDs.

Comment: You're right, I'm seeing a column of IDs and when I go and check the countryIDs are all the correct values that should be getting put into the table

Comment: @IvoBardolf so to me it sounds like you may have records in `olddb.customers` that have an empty `Country` value. That means you're trying to insert `''` into the column multiple times, and if the `CountryID` is part of the Primary Key it won't work. You either need a `WHERE` clause that sorts out old customers without the value, or if you need them you have to change your primary key to not use the CountryID.